# converting plain text information to csv or excel

Tags: text-processing

I have file containing similar data, which i am trying to arrange in the similar way, below are the details. I modified the script as per the variables in the context unable to get the required result. Probably it is due to lack of my knowledge on awk and limited knowledge on scripting.

```
Virtual_Machine  OL6U6  
Vdisk  0004fb00001200005e2ca2d2c7fc2d6f.img size 46GB
Vdisk  0004fb0000120000597ab28f2b6493f8.img size 51GB
Vdisk  0004fb00001200003edc9a2ae9cd5aa6.img size 31GB
Physical_Disk  IBM (796)
device /dev/mapper/dm-0
shareddisk true
Physical_Disk  IBM (829)
device /dev/mapper/dm-1
shareddisk true
Physical_Disk  IBM (830)
device /dev/mapper/dm-2
shareddisk true
Physical_Disk  IBM (742)
device /dev/mapper/dm-3
shareddisk true
```

I am trying go get it in the below format. Here we have two conditions.
M = Number of Physical_Disk
N = Number of Vdisk
If M > N, rows for Virtual_Machine = M
If M < N rows for Virtual_Machine = N

```
Virtual Machine      Vdisk                                     size           Physical_Disk    device              shareddisk
OL6U6               0004fb00001200005e2ca2d2c7fc2d6f.img       46GB           IBM (796)        /dev/mapper/dm-0     true
OL6U6               0004fb0000120000597ab28f2b6493f8.img       51GB           IBM (829)        /dev/mapper/dm-1     true
OL6U6               0004fb00001200003edc9a2ae9cd5aa6.img       31GB           IBM (830)        /dev/mapper/dm-2     true
OL6U6               -                                         -              IBM (742)         /dev/mapper/dm-2     true
```

Please advise.

Regards,
Darshan

Comment: and what have you tried? which part do you need help with?

Comment: I had similar requirement in past where some experts of this forum has provided suggestion and it worked. However in this case i see there is a first column in which some rows are repeating.  But corresponding rows in the second column are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with awk, by maintaining arrays for the book title and year, as well as for the papers.  In your example, there are no years for the papers, so those are simply listed in the second column as title.

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
function finish() {
    rows = book;
    if (rows < paper) rows = paper;
    for (n = 0; n <= rows; ++n) {
            printf "%-15s %-25s %-8s %s\n",
            author,
            n <= book ? books[n] : "-",
            n <= book ? years[n] : "-",
            n <= paper ? papers[n] : "-";
    }
    book = -1;
    paper = -1;
}
BEGIN {
    author = "?";
    book = -1;
    paper = -1;
    printf "Author          Books                     year     Papers\n";
}
/^[[:space:]]*Author[[:space:]]/ {
    finish();
    author = $0;
    sub("^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+", "", author);
    sub("[[:space:]]+$", "", author);
    next;
}
/^[[:space:]]*(e)?paper[[:space:]]/ {
    ++paper;
    item = $0;
    sub("^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+", "", item);
    sub("[[:space:]]+$", "", item);
    papers[paper] = item;
    next;
}
/^[[:space:]]*([eE])?[bB]ook[[:space:]].*year[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*$/ {
    ++book;
    item = $0;
    sub("^[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*", "", item);
    sub("[[:space:]]+$", "", item);
    title = item;
    sub("[[:space:]]*year[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+$", "", title);
    year = item;
    sub("^.*year[[:space:]]+", "", year);
    books[book] = title;
    years[book] = year;
    next;
}
END {
    finish();
}
```

with output:

```
$ ./foo <foo.in
Author          Books                     year     Papers
E. Narayanan    Astrophysics              2001     Intelligent Transportation
E. Narayanan    General Mechanics         2010     Nanotechnology Magazine
E. Narayanan    Nuclear physics           2011     -
R Ramesh        Organic Chemistry         2007     Ionic Batteries
R Ramesh        Physical chemistry        2008     solar photocatalytic oxidation processes
R Ramesh        -                         -        Biological oxidation
```

Comment: Thomas, i have edited the original post and made some changes, could you please review and help me with respect to it.

Comment: I modified i modified script as per my requirement but however two columns are not populated with required data. I find it quite difficult to post the modified script and output. Could you plz let me know how can i post the details here?

Comment: I have the modified script, input file and output  are available at : http://pasted.co/6313279d